# Nuxt JS - reading conf/env file in static site generation

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

My project with Nuxt JS is set with `target:static` and `ssr: false`.

This app need to connect to a local endpoint to retrieve some informations.

I have multiple endpoints and I need multiple instances of the app, every app must read only his endpoint.

The question is: how change the endpoint address for every app without rebuild everyone?

I tried with env file or a json file in the static folder (in order to have access to this file in the dist folder after the build process).

But if I modify the content of the env/json file in the dist folder and then reload the webpage (or also restart the web server that serve the dist folder), the app continue to use the original endpoint provided at the build time.

There is a way or I have to switch to server side rendering mode (which I would rather not use)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the module [nuxt content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/) it's possible to create a folder "/content" in project directory and read json files from that directory.

After, when creating the dist with nuxt generate command, the "content" folder it's included in "_nuxt" folder of the dist and if you modify the content of the json file and refresh the webpage that read it, will take the new values.

Comment: If running as SPA-only yeah.

Answer (score 1):

When you use SSG, it will bundle your app at build time. Last time I checked, there was no hack regarding that. (I don't have the Github issue under my hand but it's a popular one)

And at the same time, I don't really see how it would be done since you want to mix something static and dynamic at the same time.

SSR is the only way here.
Otherwise, you may have some other logic to generate dynamic markup when updating your endpoints (not related to Nuxt) by fetching a remote endpoint I guess.